# Pandas Scatter Plot: Indices Out-of-Bounds

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plot, scatter

I have a simple Pandas dataframe:

[image: simple df]

`delta`, `start_hour`, and `end_hour` are all `numpy.int64`:

```
type(df.delta[0])
->numpy.int64
```

Whenever I try to use the Pandas methods to do a scatter plot, I get "IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds".  For example:

```
sc2 = df.plot.scatter(x=df.delta, y=df.start_hour)
```

produces:

`IndexError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-4d521c29b97f> in <module>()
----> 1 sc2 = df.plot.scatter(x=df.delta, y=df.start_hour)`

...
`/mnt/xarfuse/uid-116535/[edit]/pandas/core/indexing.pyc in maybe_convert_indices(indices, n)
IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds`

I've also tried explicit conversion to Numpy arrays, as described in [this post](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3340/):

```
df_x = np.array(df['delta'].tolist())
df_y = np.array(df['start_hour'].tolist())
sc1 = df.plot.scatter(x=df_x, y=df_y)
```

which produces the same error.

I am sure I'm missing something *really* simple.  Help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass df['delta'] to `x` it will be like `df[df['delta']]` which returns a `key error : not in index`, so you have to simply pass the column names to scatter method as x and y values i.e

```
sc2 = df.plot.scatter(x='delta', y='start_hour')
```

Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'delta':[162,9,9,38,691,58],'start_hour':[1,5,11,1,7,6],'last_hour':[3,5,11,2,19,7]})
sc2 = df.plot.scatter(x='delta', y='start_hour')
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want to pass the numpy array then dont search for it in df. i.e direclty use `plt.scatter` eg

```
df_x = np.array(df['delta'].tolist())
df_y = np.array(df['start_hour'].tolist())
plt.scatter(x=df_x, y=df_y)
plt.show()
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you!  That did, indeed, fix the problem!